# Flatpicker defaultHours and defaultMinute not working

Tags: django, date, datetime, datetimepicker

I am trying to change the default time when a date is selected in Flatpicker, but every time I select a date, the time is always 12:00 or another value if the time was already there when retrieved by Django. I cannot find a way to set the current time upon selection of the date.

```
$('.datepicker').flatpickr({
    dateFormat: "d-m-Y H:i:S",
    enableTime: true,
    // enableSeconds: true,
    allowInput: true,
    time_24hr: true,
    minuteIncrement: 1,
    defaultHour: new Date().getHours(),
    defaultMinute: new Date().getMinutes(),
});
```